# Timer in asp.net to execute code every 2 minutes twice

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timer

I have a button that when its clicked it will start a stored procedure to execute a sql job. In the button I have a method. In the method, I would like to the code to wait 2 minutes and run a sql query to get the status, if the status = 4 or the status = 7 then to stop, but if the status is not 4 or 7, then the same code to run again in two minutes, but only twice. How can I implement this in vb.net website? Below is what I've tried so far but I'm getting errors, I have never done a time before.

```
   Dim myTimer As New System.Timers.Timer(2 * 60 * 1000)
   Private Sub DisableButton()
      btnBertFish.Enabled = False
      myTimer.Elapsed = New ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf (OnTimedEvent()))
   End Sub
   Private Sub OnTimedEvent()
   'Some code that need to execute
   End Sub
```

So, far these are the errors I get: Public Event Elapsed(sender as object, e as System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) is an event, and cannot be called directly. User a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

I've looked at tutorials and at System.Timers, but I can't figure out how to even start. Can someone please help me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: 1) Your event syntax is wrong; see the documentation.  2) You can't do that at all; this runs on the server.  You need to use Javascript.

Comment: How can I start a piece of code from javascript?

Comment: Are you asking how to call a Your question is meaningless.  Javascript _is_ code.

Comment: I know Javascript is a code. What I was asking is how can I execute a vb.net code through Javascript.

Comment: You can use AJAX.  However, that isn't what you want either; you should use Javascript to manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim myTimer As New System.Timers.Timer()
 myTimer .AutoReset = True
 myTimer .Interval = 60 * 1000 '1 minute
 AddHandler myTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
 dim i as integer=0
 Private Sub DisableButton()
    btnBertFish.Enabled = False
    myTimer.Elapsed = New ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf (OnTimedEvent()))
 End Sub   
 Private Sub OnTimedEvent()
 i += 1
 if i= 2 then
 ' Run your code
 'i=2 means the second tick of the timer since i value is increased in each 1 minute
 End IF
 End Sub
```

Add `myTimer.Start()` in the event where you need a delay, to stop the timer or reset add the code with the timer block but i don't get a clear idea about what is `thestatus`:

```
 if theStatus = 4 or theStatus = 7 then
 myTimer.Stop()
 else
 i=0
 End If
```